# combine rows from two dataframes on the nth row r

Tags: r, merge

I want to combine two dataframes for every other row in df1 I want to insert two rows from df2.

df1:

```
Chr     Start       End nProbes nA nB loss gain amp cnloh
23    168477   2693175     429  1  1    0    0   0     0
23   2693624  58561930   33605  1  0    1    0   0     0
23  61728829 154973412   50990  0  0    1    0   0     0
23 154977448 155233846      31  1  1    0    0   0     0
```

df2:

```
Chr     Start       End nProbes nA nB loss gain amp cnloh
23   2693175   2694073   33605  1  1    1    0   0     0
23   2694073   2693624   33605  1  1    1    0   0     0
23  58561930  64895728   50990  1  0    1    0   0     0
23  64895728  61728829   50990  1  0    1    0   0     0
23 154973412 154981484      31  0  0    0    0   0     0
23 154981484 154977448      31  0  0    0    0   0     0
```

output:

```
Chr     Start       End nProbes nA nB loss gain amp cnloh
23    168477   2693175     429  1  1    0    0   0     0
23   2693175   2694073   33605  1  1    1    0   0     0
23   2694073   2693624   33605  1  1    1    0   0     0
23   2693624  58561930   33605  1  0    1    0   0     0
23  58561930  64895728   50990  1  0    1    0   0     0
23  64895728  61728829   50990  1  0    1    0   0     0
23  61728829 154973412   50990  0  0    1    0   0     0
23 154973412 154981484      31  0  0    0    0   0     0
23 154981484 154977448      31  0  0    0    0   0     0
23 154977448 155233846      31  1  1    0    0   0     0
```

Comment: Can you provide us with some simulated data that is easy to copy/paste and also what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
#create an id column for both dfs
#this id will dictate the order of rows
df1$id <- 1:nrow(df1)
df2$id <- rep(1:(nrow(df2)/2),each=2)

#rbind the two data.frames
df3 <- rbind(df1, df2)
#and now just order based on their ids
df3 <- df3[order(df3$id), ]
```

Ouput:

```
> df3
   Chr     Start       End nProbes nA nB loss gain amp cnloh id
1   23    168477   2693175     429  1  1    0    0   0     0  1
5   23   2693175   2694073   33605  1  1    1    0   0     0  1
6   23   2694073   2693624   33605  1  1    1    0   0     0  1
2   23   2693624  58561930   33605  1  0    1    0   0     0  2
7   23  58561930  64895728   50990  1  0    1    0   0     0  2
8   23  64895728  61728829   50990  1  0    1    0   0     0  2
3   23  61728829 154973412   50990  0  0    1    0   0     0  3
9   23 154973412 154981484      31  0  0    0    0   0     0  3
10  23 154981484 154977448      31  0  0    0    0   0     0  3
4   23 154977448 155233846      31  1  1    0    0   0     0  4
```

You can then easily delete the id column using `df3$id <- NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

rbind(df1, df2) will do it if both dataframes have the same column names. 
Afterwards you can remove double rows by duplicated.

```
newdf <- rbind(df1, df2)
newdf <- newdf[duplicated(newdf) == FALSE, ]
```

Regards, 
Florian

Comment: i should edit this with real data! there are no similar variable names.